# Docker: unable to acces other files in directory

Tags: docker, python-2.7

I'm new to docker and I'm trying to create a docker image in which a python 2.7 script runs. This file imports functions and classes from other files in the same directory. Building the docker image already works, but running it gives an error that the imported files in the python 2.7 script don't exist.

This is the dockerfile I'm using

```
FROM python:2.7

WORKDIR C:\something\something\print

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install python-cairo
RUN apt-get install python-gi
RUN apt-get install python-gi-cairo
RUN apt-get install -y gir1.2-gtk-3.0
RUN apt-get install -y mapnik-utils
RUN pip install bs4
RUN pip install image
RUN pip install mapnik
RUN pip install numpy
RUN pip install psycopg2
COPY test_server.py ./

CMD [ "python", "./test_server.py"]
```

And this is the error I receive after I do "docker run"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_server.py", line 13, in <module>
    from utils import client, reprojector, formats
ImportError: No module named utils
```

The module named utils is a folder in the WORKDIR I specified in the dockerfile, but I don't understand why it can't be accessed. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try add the parent folder of utils into environment `PYTHONPATH`, for your case, add `ENV PYTHONPATH=.` in Dockerfile to tell python to find `utils` from WORKDIR

Comment: That doesn't seem to solve my problem sadly. Is there a specific place where I should be adding this line?

Comment: From your Dockerfile, there is no directive to copy `utils` module/package to image,  can you add directive to cofnfirm where the `utils` is in image and what files under it via `RUN ls -l && ls -l utils`